# Вывод неизвестного типа данных в СИ

Tags: c, массивы, вывод

Не знаю, как реализовать вывод массива собственного типа в СИ, т. к. нужны спецификаторы.

```
template <class X, class Y>
void display (X *ms, Y *size) //вывод массива
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  { 
    printf("%что тут поставить?", ms[i]);
  }
}`
```

Comment: Что значит "неизвестного"? Вот же он - `X`

Comment: Что это такое вообще? Какое `template` в Си???

Comment: Определитесь с языком и поставьте правильный тег. Это С или С++?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat:  В тексте вопроса ясно сказано несколько раз - Си и именно Си. Поэтому - убрать нафиг `template`. Если ТС хотел с `template` - пусть задает новый вопрос, думая головой при этом, что он пишет.

Comment: @AnT Подумал, откатил правку. Некоторые из моих знакомых-студентов называют С++ просто "Си", может дело в этом... Хорошо бы от ТС ответ получить.

Comment: @Ant, тема именно связана с Си.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Почему нужно убирать template? Я создал новый класс, который использую, чтобы не копипастить функции для разных типов данных.

Comment: @DPAKOLLA; Что значит "тема именно связана с Си"? Ваш код написан на C++, но при этом в тегах нет С++, а есть С. Это как?

Comment: Насколько я помню, в C++ есть спасающий cout.
(на данный момент разница в Си и крестах для меня заключается в вводе/выводе, массивах (vector) и еще некоторых особенностях. )

Comment: @DPAKOLLA в Си в отличи от "крестов" нет ни классов, ни уж тем более шаблонов. У вас подобный код с кусками С++ скомпилируется только потому что вы сидите в какой-нибудь VS с компилятором под С++, ничего общего template'ы c Си не имеют.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, к сожалению, я не еще силен в таких особенностях. Да, сижу в Visual Strudio с компилятором под C++

Comment: @DPAKOLLA, так в итоге то вам что нужно, код на чистом Си или все же на С++?

Comment: на С++ без использования std, cout'ов и cin'ов, векторов и т.д.

Comment: @DPAKOLLA, ну т.е. на С++, но без всего, что есть в С++, кроме tamplate'ов? Странная идея, но дело конечно ваше...

Comment: Я решил задачу через sizeof из Си (только палками не бейте, если это не из Си), сравниваю к-во байт, занимающее элементом массива, если int (4), то вывод со спецификатором "%d" и т.д.
(Только я забыл, что просто так double не сравнить)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, template я использовал из-за нехватки информации о возможности решения проблемы.

Comment: @DPAKOLLA, вас никто "бить" и не собирался. Вопрос в том, что компилятор под чистый Си не скомпилирует ваш код. По решению: int может и не весить 4 байта на некоторых платформах, float зачастую тоже занимает 4 байта. Если у вас конкретная задача с конкретными примерами - лучше добавить это в вопрос :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, изначально смысл  вопроса - функция с реализацией вывода массива разного типа

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что именно имеется в виду под "неизвестного"? Этот тип `X` вообще в принципе является непосредственно поддерживаемым `printf`?

- Наиболее простое и дешевое решение: если вы знаете, что `X` заведомо принадлежит к какой-то категории скалярных типов, то выводить его можно через приведение к "самому универсальному" типу в этой категории. Например, если `X` - это всегда некий *знаковый целочисленный тип*, то выводимое значение можно явно привести к какому-нибудь конкретному самому широкому знаковому целочисленному типу и использовать его спецификатор формата

  ```
  printf("%lld\n", (long long) ms[i]);
  ```

  или лучше

  ```
  printf("%" PRIdMAX "\n", (intmax_t) ms[i]);
  ```

  (и аналогичным образом для остальных категорий скалярных типов).
- Если `X` - это некое typedef-имя для типа, которое может меняться, но при этом допускает непосредственный вывод через `printf`, то там, где вы определяли `X` надо определить и правильный спецификатор формата для его вывода. Например

  ```
  typedef unsigned long X;
  #define X_FMT "lu"

  ...
  printf("%" X_FMT "\n", ms[i]);
  ```
- Альтернативный вариант - реализация автоматического выбора формата для всех возможных типов `X` через `_Generic`.
- Если же тип `X` не является непосредственно выводимым через `printf`, то унифицировать его вывод придется другими способами. Например, в спецификаторе формата писать всегда `%s`, а в качестве выводимого аргумента уже использовать результат какой-то универсальной функции "преобразования в строковый формат", которая, возможно, реализуется вышеописанными способами.

Comment: А если `X` это typedef некой структуры?

Comment: @avp: Это уже вопрос к ТС. Непосредственный вывод структуры через `printf` - это невозможно в принципе. Имелось ли в виду что-то подобное?

Comment: @Ant Можете пояснить строку с директивой?

Comment: @DPAKOLLA: О какой именно директиве идет речь?

Comment: @AnT #define X_FMT "lu"

Comment: @DPAKOLLA: Ну это обыкновенный макрос. В коде `X_FMT` будет заменяться на `"lu"`, то есть получится `printf("%" "lu" "\n", ms[i]);`. Соседние строковые литералы в С всегда автоматически склеиваются, т.е. в итоге получится `printf("%lu\n", ms[i]);` - то, что нам и надо.

Comment: @AnT, ну, да. Вот вы как раз и уточнили это в своем обновлении

Comment: Мне кажется, человек хотел обобщенного программирования - раз templates - так что ваш ответ не годится: нет спецификатора для выводимого компилятором типа.\

Comment: @Mikhailo: `template` там появилось только после недавнего изменения. Вопрос изначально (и сейчас) помечен тегом [C]. В тексте везде ясно сказано. что речь идет о "Си". Никакого `template` в языке С нет. Сейчас вопрос представляет собой какую-то чушь.

Comment: Так я ж и говворю, что это с++! и надо пользоваться cout<<.

Comment: @Mikhailo: Мой ответ относится к исходному вопросу по языку Си. Если вы сказать, что "это С++", то направлять свои заявления вы должны автору вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по исходнику, интересует С++ (раз template). А в нем применять `printf` не следует, не годится С для обобщенного программирования!

Используйте `cout <<` - и все будет правильно!